# Are the levels of warriors mentioned in any shastra in detail?

Tags: scripture, puranas

The levels such as Rathi, Atirathi, Maharathi, Atimaharathi and Mahamaharathi.

Are these really mentioned in scripture or just fictional.

Does any scripture describe the criteria to be called as one of it.

Comment: Many of those words do appear in certain passages of the Mahabharatha, but none of them mention the exact criteria. Let me know if you're interested in those specific passages.